# Using l'Hopital's Rule on two trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have to use the l'Hopital's Rule to find the limit of:
$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{1 - \sin(x)}$$

If I plug in $\pi/2$, I can see that this is a $0/0$ case, so I must use the rule.

The derivative of the numerator and the derivative of the denominator would come out to be this I believe:
$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{-\sin(x)}{-\cos(x)}$$
which is just $\tan(x)$

if I plug in $\pi/2$, to the derivative, I get $1/0$, which is undefined. However the correct answer seems to be $-\infty$ and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of limits $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$, however the limit should be $x \to (\pi/2)^{+}$ to be $-\infty$; written like this the limit doesn't exist because it is different if you approach to $\pi/2$ from left or from right.

Comment: If I may ask, why is the limit -∞ when approached from the right? How would this even look on a graph?

Comment: @RudyGoburt:  see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+cos+x%2F%281-+sin+x%29+as+x+approaches+pi%2F2)

Comment: @RudyGoburt: It is a matter of sign: the notation "$x \to (\pi/2)^{+}$" means "$x$ is approaching $\pi/2$ from the right", so informally you can think $(\pi/2)^{+}$ as a number which is a tiny little bigger than $\pi/2$, like $\pi/2+0.01$. In that situation, the sine is positive and the cosine is negative and so their ratio is negative and you get something like $\frac{1}{0^{-}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that through L'Hopital's rule, you get

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \tan x$$

As you say, $\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is undefined, but that doesn't mean you should stop. What you should do is look at the graph of $f(x)=\tan x$. You'll see that as $x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left, the graph goes to inifinity; as $x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the right, the graph goes to negative infinity. As a result, **the limit does not exist.**